# It is good practice to create our own custom ValidationSummary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the sense of common tools and staying vanilla with MVC. It is good practice to create our own custom ValidationSummary to handle a specific scenario ? If yes, do you have Microsoft links or orientation to back this ?

Comment: Could you give a specific scenario? Are you using data annotation in your model? Or using scripts with jquery validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is good practice to create our own custom ValidationSummary to handle a specific scenario?

Definitely! We should be giving users feedback about incorrect input, especially in specific cases identified by the business. We've got a couple different built-in ways to expand on the default validation to handle specific scenarios:

- Custom attributes can derive from base classes like the [ValidationAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) class.
- You can implement the [IValidateableObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject(v=vs.110).aspx) interface on models for custom validation.
- You can add the [IClientValidatable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.118).aspx) interface to validation attributes to hook into client-side validation.

> If yes, do you have Microsoft links or orientation to back this?

Here are three MSDN articles about various kinds of MVC validation:

1. [How to: Customize Data Field Validation in the Data Model Using Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224.aspx)
2. [Best Practices for ASP.NET MVC](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aspnetue/2010/09/17/best-practices-for-asp-net-mvc/)
3. [Entity Framework Validation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193959.aspx)